# Terminal edited files cannot be run by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse on linux, and I have mostly been writing java files by editing the raw text file.  My reasoning behind this is that I am in a comp sci course, and we have to write code by hand, so this will prepare me for writing code unaided.  However, my actual problem arose when I tried to edit a file I had created using eclipse 3.8.1.  When I tried to open the folder, which has the same structure as files created by eclipse if it matters, it opens, but I cannot run it.  When I click run, it asks what to run it as, and the only 2 options are Ant Builds.  I don't know what this means, but I am not able to run the file either way.  Any help is appreciated, and if it is important, I am using java 8.

Comment: Eclipse has a somewhat obtuse package management system. You'll want to import your files. Create a new Java project in eclipse. Then use "File > Import..." - "General > File System" and import it. Also, if you edit the files outside of eclipse you'll need to "refresh" them in eclipse. Really, you should edit in eclipse (if you intend to use it).

Comment: Also, you should be editing your code in Eclipse.  The syntax-sensitive tools are very helpful and will save a lot of time.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you.  This worked properly.

Comment: @JimGarrison As I said in my question, I am preparing to be writing code by hand, so I am getting used to writing code without the syntax tools.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you have a file you 'created with [eclipse]' and that the only options you have to "run" it are ant builds. We don't know what you are clicking on. We don't know if you are refreshing the project folders in eclipse after you change files in your editor (it is important to do this). You might consider either doing this entirely with eclipse or without, but not mix them. I appreciate that you want to know how to do this without eclipse, but I think it might make things more difficult for you.

Comment: @arcy *A man who carries a cat by the tail learns something he can learn in no other way.* **-** Mark Twain